# How to get category on home page wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, triggers

i need to show my category on my custom homepage.
Here is my code

```
<?php query_posts('cat=1&showposts=5'); ?>
```

This is working perfect.I have lms plugin and i want to show my plugin category on home page. Same code i am using here.

```
<?php query_posts('course_cat=1&showposts=5'); ?>
```

But, blank page coming. Any help ?

Comment: Should `course_cat` be `cat`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this Call the category by name (using its slug).And show the post within the while loop

```
    <?php 
    query_posts('category_name=blog&showposts=5'); 
     while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
        the_title();
        the_excerpt();
    endwhile; // end of the loop. 
    ?>
```

Comment: You really shouldn't use `query_posts`, [basically ever](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts).

Comment: Pooja i am using LMS plugin. The LMS have different category structure. Here LMS category "course_cat" not default wordpress category. <?php query_posts('course_cat=1&showposts=5'); ?>

Comment: Ashok are you created a custom post?

Comment: Its an customized plugin have same function as default wordpress use. Course = (means post) and Course category = ( same like category).

Comment: If some how you are able to find the category slug from the core files.Then you can easily show that category to your custom post.

Answer (score -1):

From [Wordpress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts):

> Note: This function isn't meant to be used by plugins or themes. As explained later, there are better, more performant options to alter the main query. query_posts() is overly simplistic and problematic way to modify main query of a page by replacing it with new instance of the query. It is inefficient (re-runs SQL queries) and will outright fail in some circumstances (especially often when dealing with posts pagination). Any modern WP code should use more reliable methods, like making use of [pre_get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) hook, for this purpose.

Comment: While you're right about `query_posts` not being recommended for use in this scenario, this post does not provide an answer to the original question.